# OpenERP Server Error Access denied

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo, putty

After installing Odoo, I went to web panel where it asked create new database.

As I entered details I got error. I can change master password successfully.
I already created database on putty and there is no openerp-server.conf file under /etc/ folder.

```
    Odoo
OpenERP Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 517, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 284, in _call_function
    return self.endpoint(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 733, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 714, in create
    params['create_admin_pwd'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 807, in proxy_method
    result = dispatch_rpc(self.service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 100, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/db.py", line 62, in dispatch
    security.check_super(passwd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/security.py", line 33, in check_super
    raise openerp.exceptions.AccessDenied()
AccessDenied: Access denied.
```

Comment: this will help to find locate of .conf file => `locate openerp-server.conf` Open that file and check out master password weather is same as you given while creating a new database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using following command you will get location of .conf file

```
locate openerp-server.conf
```

Now go to that path and open it and check out master password whether it's same as you given while creating a new database.

Comment: If you haven't specified a config file, or your config file doesn't contain a `db_password` value then the default master password is `admin`

Comment: There's no "master" password to be found on the default odoo-server.confg file: Theres a commented "admin password" and another called "db_password".

Answer (score 6):

@Danish the master password should be "**admin**" it is required to newly create your database

Answer (score 2):

The master password that you are using to create the database is not same as what you have set for the PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 0):

@Danish

1. Check the tools -> config file and look what are the username and
   password been set for accessing the database.
2. Check pg_hba.conf file under /etc/postgresql/9.1/main, that it is
   allowing the connection for the specified database user in tools ->
   config file.