# Openerp during backup from interface says access denied

Tags: backup, odoo

I restored database from backup and renamed it to original and deleted the faulty one. The system is working but backup says access denied.
I checked the process and the process that is running pg_dump goes stalled in zambi mode.

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenERP Server Error Access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202448/openerp-server-error-access-denied)

Comment: No it is not the same